# passing parameter from an angular table to another one

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework, restangular, smart-table

I have an angular smart-table of customers what I want is:

=> When I select one customer, I display another table with contacts of the customer that I had selected.

So how to pass the id of the customer to the second table?

Thank you in advance

Update:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                                <table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="ref" class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>id</th>
                                            <th>rDescription</th>
                                            <th>rLanguage</th>
                                            <th>lastVersion</th>
                                            <th>linkSet</th>
                                            <th>Actions</th>
                                        </tr>
                                            <th colspan="5">
            <input st-search="{{selectedPredicate}}" placeholder="bound predicate" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
        </th>

                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                     <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection" data-ng-click="select(row)">
          <td>{{row._id}}</td>

          <td>{{row.rDescription}}</td>
          <td>{{row.rLanguage}}</td>
          <td>{{row.lastVersion}}</td>
          <td>{{row.linkSet}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">
                                                <div class="btn-group">


                                                      <button class="Details" ng-click="Details(row);">Details</button> 
                                                </div>

                                            </td>
        </tr>

                                    </tbody>

                                </table>
```

and this is my controller where I just get my id (for test):

```
app.controller("listctrl",["$scope","Restangular",function($scope,Restangular){

    $scope.ref = Restangular.all("referential").getList().$object;
    $scope.predicates = ['rDescription', 'rLanguage', 'lastVersion', 'linkSet'];
    $scope.selectedPredicate = $scope.predicates[0];

   $scope.SaveData = function(row) {
        alert("coucou " + row._id);
    };

}]);
```

what I need to do now is to share id between my two controllers is this the right way ?

```
app.controller("listctrl",["$scope","Restangular",function($scope,Restangular){

    $scope.ref = Restangular.all("referential").getList().$object;
    $scope.predicates = ['rDescription', 'rLanguage', 'lastVersion', 'linkSet'];
    $scope.selectedPredicate = $scope.predicates[0];

   $scope.SaveData = function(row) {
        return row._id;
    };

}]);

  app.controller("listdetailctrl", function ($scope , SaveData) {
    $scope.refe = Restangular.one("referential",SaveData).getList();

  });
```

Also I'm asking if there is a better way to do this:
(the second table is hidden until we click on button

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far ? please provide us some code that you have tried so far

Comment: I'm a beginner, I searched in the internet but I didn't find an example of how to get parameter in the angular controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do pass you customer id by click event in angular by ng-click and by passing object containing id for particular index no.
eg.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in customer">
<td>{{x.id}} <input type="button" ng-click="getDetails(x.id)"></td>
<td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
<td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
```

Comment: and how can I get the id in the angular controller?

Comment: from where are you fetching customer table details. Post some code you are using.

Comment: you ll have to write an angular service to share id between multiple controllers. You cannot share id directly from one controller to other